# Keyboard Overlapping Input After Validation Error in KeyboardAvoidingView and ScrollView

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I've been struggling with this issue for a very long time. Currently, the `KeyboardAvoidingView` in combination with the `ScrollView` is working perfectly on both Android and iOS devices. However, I have the following problem. When I click the "Continue" button, it automatically switches to the next input, which also works perfectly. Until the point where a validation input error occurs. This adds additional content below the input, and the keyboard suddenly partially covers the input. When you press a key again, the view adjusts automatically. How can I resolve this issue?

Without validation error messages (working fine):

[image: Without validation error messages]

With validation error message appearing on blur (broken):

[image: With validation error message appearing on blur]

Code

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}
behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
>
  <ScrollView>
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <RHFTextField<Schema>
        name="1"
        placeholder="Email"
        keyboardType="email-address"
        returnKeyType="next"
        blurOnSubmit={false}
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          field2.current?.focus()
        }}
      />
      // multiple inputs
    </FormProvider>
  </ScrollView>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

My `RHFTextField` is displaying the error conditionally as follows:

```
{error && <Text style={styles.errorText}>{error.message}</Text>}
```

`keyboardVerticalOffset` does not help at all.